# sonar-runner fails every time

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

While running sonar-runner (with debug flags, and stack trace) I'm getting an error.

My sonar server is bound to mysql which runs on the same machine. It was running ok for some time, but lately it have started ending with following error.

```
 10:25:23.030 DEBUG - 178223 measures to dump
 10:25:23.629 DEBUG - Updating semaphore batch-test:test1
 10:25:33.739 DEBUG - Updating semaphore batch-test:test1
 10:25:43.968 DEBUG - Updating semaphore batch-test:test1
 10:25:49.551 INFO  - Store results in database
 10:25:49.551 DEBUG - Execute org.sonar.batch.index.ComponentDataPersister
 10:25:54.151 DEBUG - Updating semaphore batch-test:test1
 10:26:02.159 DEBUG - Execute org.sonar.batch.issue.IssuePersister
 10:26:02.196 DEBUG - ooo Using Connection [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8, UserName=sonar@localhost, MySQL Connector Java]
 10:26:02.196 DEBUG - ==>  Preparing: select * from projects p WHERE p.kee=?
 10:26:02.196 DEBUG - ==> Parameters: test:test1:com.test.framework.gba.GbaInfoProvider(String)
 10:26:02.198 DEBUG - Release semaphore on project : org.sonar.api.resources.Project@45de530a[id=2644,key=test:test1,qualifier=TRK], with key batch-test:test1
 10:26:02.281 DEBUG - To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] has been forcibly deregistered
 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Total time: 27:30.454s
 Final Memory: 27M/872M
```

Any ideas why it fails?

Comment: There must be a stack trace under Final Memory...

Comment: I have reinstalled sonar, cleaned the database and also cleaned the generated .cache. Seems to work now. Regarding the missing stack trace - i forgot to pipe the error stream to output stream and the error logs didn't gather.